# How to modify the javascript AST in an eslint rule fix

Tags: javascript, eslint, rule

I am currently working on an eslint rule whose fix should strip a chained attributes.

In the current example `b` should be stripped, so

```js
a.b() // or
a.b.c()
```

should become:

```js
a() // or
a.c()
```

My first draft naively takes the given part of the source and removes the unwanted attribute:

```js
fix: fixer => {
  const range = getChainedAttribute(node, 'b').range;
  range[0] -= 1; // strip also the prepending dot
  return fixer.remove(getChainedAttribute(node, 'b'));
}
```

(`getChainedAttribute` is a helper function which returns the chained attribute.)

Although this fix works as intended, it fails with the following exception from eslint:

```js
Rule should not modify AST.

Actual:
[object Object]

Expected:
[object Object]

assertASTDidntChange (node_modules/eslint/lib/testers/rule-tester.js:406:24)
...
```

How to overcome this drawback to be able stripping a chained attribute/method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late to the party but recently had a similar issue and managed to fix it.
I think the issue is in these 2 lines:

```
const range = getChainedAttribute(node, 'b').range;
range[0] -= 1; // strip also the prepending dot
```

You're changing the AST range directly, that's why `eslint` is complaining, if you do:

```
const range = [...getChainedAttribute(node, 'b').range];
range[0] -= 1; // strip also the prepending dot
```

That fixed it for me.
Hope it helps you or future readers.